# Django Get request returns empty array if I do not duplicate the API endpoint

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have been struggling for the past 2 months with very strange behavior that I can not pin down.

One of my django app urls file looks like this:

```
urlpatterns = {
    path('containers/', GetProductContainers.as_view()),
    path('delete/<deleteTime>', DeleteProcessedStockTime.as_view()),
    path('containers/', GetProductContainers.as_view()),
    path('input/', InsertMultiProcessedStock.as_view()),
    path('<str:stockT>/', ProcessedStockTimeView.as_view(), name="stockstime"),
    path('', ProductListDetailsView.as_view(), name="details"),
}
```

As you can see, this path `path('containers/', GetProductContainers.as_view()),` is twice in my urlpatterns. The reason for this is that as soon as I remove one, it returns an empty array. **It does not matter which one I remove!** If both are there, I get the 319 records that I expect. I can remove ANY one of the two, and it will return an empty array, but as soon as I have 2 it works again.

Can anyone think of an explanation for this or how I can even begin to debug it?

Comment: It's common practice to use `list` for urlpatterns, not `set`. Not sure it's the reason of error by try to change type: `urlpatterns = [...]`.

Comment: Thank you, I will try when I get back to work tomorrow and see if it changes anything. Regards

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe that this is because you create urlpatterns as a set and not as a list.
A set is an **unordered** type, so url patterns will not be resolved in the correct order.

Example:

```
>>> {
...     path('containers/', TestView.as_view()),
...     path('delete/<deleteTime>', TestView.as_view()),
...     path('input/', TestView.as_view()),
...     path('<str:stockT>/', TestView.as_view(), name="stockstime"),
...     path('', TestView.as_view(), name="details"),
... }
{<URLPattern '<str:stockT>/' [name='stockstime']>, <URLPattern '' [name='details']>, <URLPattern 'containers/'>, <URLPattern 'delete/<deleteTime>'>, <URLPattern 'input/'>}


>>> [
...     path('containers/', TestView.as_view()),
...     path('delete/<deleteTime>', TestView.as_view()),
...     path('input/', TestView.as_view()),
...     path('<str:stockT>/', TestView.as_view(), name="stockstime"),
...     path('', TestView.as_view(), name="details"),
... ]
[<URLPattern 'containers/'>, <URLPattern 'delete/<deleteTime>'>, <URLPattern 'input/'>, <URLPattern '<str:stockT>/' [name='stockstime']>, <URLPattern '' [name='details']>]
```

Comment: In other words, your /containers/ URL is being interpreted as the string parameter to stockstime, so it is returning a list of elements from that view that match "containers", of which there are none.

Comment: Thank goodness! That looks to have solved the problem that manifested itself in many different ways. Thanks!